# Display results to another php page from a select statement using a function

Tags: php

I had a hard time solving this: Need help pls..

Here's my original code:

---

**function.php**

```
public function getTestScriptSummary($projectID){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_test_script_header WHERE fld_projectID='$projectID'";
    $query = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $testResults .= "
            <tr>
                <td style=\"padding:3px;\">".$row['fld_dateEnded']."</td>
                <td style=\"padding:3px;\">".$row['fld_testerName']."</td>
                <td style=\"padding:3px;\">".$row['fld_scriptID']."</td>
                <td style=\"padding:3px;\">".$row['fld_testPhase']."</td>
                <td style=\"padding:3px;\">".$row['fld_status']."</td>
            </tr>"; 
    }
    return $testResults;
}
```

**view.php**

```
  echo $User->getTestScriptSummary($_POST['projectName']);
```

---

With this code, I got the right answers. But I dont want to display the table (the value in the testResults i mean) here in my function. Instead i want it to display in the view.php. How will i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This will combine the results into single array.

```
$testResults =array();
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $testResults[] = $row;
}
return $testResults;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was a quick answer. Problem solved.